# Magento error: Invalid backend model specified: customer_entity/address_attribute_backend_region

Tags: magento

After updating my magento instance from 1.4.0 to 1.7.0.2 I've got the following error:

```
Invalid backend model specified: customer_entity/address_attribute_backend_region
```

The error occurs during the checkout process while the customer is selecting the adress from drop-down list and press the "continue" button.

A AJAX-request to /checkout/onepage/saveBilling/ fails, the second request to checkout/onepage/getAdditional responses. The customer will be redirected to the cart overview page, but content the failed ajax response displays an error report number, which can be looked up at with FTP in the folder var/reports/####reportnumber###.log

EDIT: Stack trace

```
a:5:{i:0;s:81:"Invalid backend model specified: customer_entity/address_attribute_backend_region";i:1;s:1907:"#0 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
#1 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1094): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
#2 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(998): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_setAttributeValue(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Address), Array)
#3 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(959): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_loadModelAttributes(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Address))
#4 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Address), '209', NULL)
#5 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('209')
#6 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(320): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveBilling(Array, '209')
#7 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveBillingAction()
#8 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveBilling')
#9 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/www/p10000/html/magento/index.php(101): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:60:"/magento/index.php/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:11:"german";}
```

Comment: Where is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this topic: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/261499/#t350593

So I created this statement (the first two lines I found at learningmagento.com, but they are incomplete and leads into a total break of the onepage/saveBilling-Page, if you don't change the source model, too.

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `backend_model` = 'customer/entity_address_attribute_backend_street' WHERE `attribute_code` ='street' LIMIT 1 ;
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `backend_model` = 'customer/entity_address_attribute_backend_region' WHERE `attribute_code` ='region' LIMIT 1 ;

UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `source_model` = 'customer/entity_address_attribute_source_country' WHERE `source_model` = 'customer_entity/address_attribute_source_country' LIMIT 1 ;
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `source_model` = 'customer/entity_address_attribute_source_region' WHERE `source_model` ='customer_entity/address_attribute_source_region' LIMIT 1 ;
```

It worked for me. The AJAX request responses with a validation error for the phone number in my case, but this can be solved easily.

The "customer_entity/..." can be also found in the table "eav_entity_type", but in my case it was (not yet) necessary to change the value.